# Which statistical test to compare same model with different parameters?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, aic, likelihood-ratio, model-comparison

I have two datasets on people buying apples based on weight and price. One dataset in 2019 the other in 2020.

I estimate a logit model with Utility = betaWeight * weight + betaPrice * price.

Training on 2019 I obtain Model2019 -> betaWeight = 1, betaPrice = 2

Training on 2020 I obtain Model2020 -> betaWeight = 1, betaPrice = 4

I want to have a statistical test, saying the model of 2020 is better than the one of 2019 to explain the data in 2020. Basically, the difference in the estimated parameters is not due to a sampling error, but it is real.

If I compute the likelihood for predicting data of 2020:

L0 = Null log likelihood = -3500

L2019 = Log likelihood using Model2019 = -1100

L2020 = Log likelihood using Model2020 = -1020

Should I use the likelihood ratio test? Akaike test?

Thanks

Comment: how are you computing the likelihood? what assumption? to compare between different models one common approach is to take the correlation between predicted and actual (spearman or pearson) and then calculate a p-value for that. This isn't a test for one being better than the other but it might show that one is significant and the other isn't.

Comment: I'm using maximum likelihood estimation (software biogeme). Correlation is for continuous variables, here I have a classification (each data point is a choice between different apples). I can compare the R2, showing the one of 2020 is higher, but how much higher is significant?

Comment: You want to compare the performance of the two models on the same dataset? So model 1's score on  2020 data vs model 2's score on 2020 data?

Comment: yes. Of course model2 will perform better, since it is trained on that data.

Comment: Are the people in 2019 the same as in 2020, so panel data with two observations per person? Or are they different people? Or something in between?

Answer (score 0):

To test that the model built on one data set is better performing than the model built on the other data set:

Let predictions of model 1 be called $y_i$ and predictions of model 2 be called $z_i$. We want to show that $z_i$ is usually more correct than $y_i$. Define a score metric for every sample and run a paired t-test to determine that $score(z_i) > score(y_i)$.

See [here](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/meancomp.htm)

What you do is:
Let $d_i = (score(z_i) - score(y_i))$ and $d$ be the average of $d_i$ over all samples. Let $s_d$ be the standard deviation over $d_i$.
let $t = \frac{d}{\frac{s_d}{\sqrt{n}}}$

This test statistic follows a t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

You mentioned the problem is classification. A common loss function for individual samples in classification problems are 0-1 loss or brier score.

Comment: Since both models are being evaluated on the same dataset, wouldn't it make sense to use a paired t-test?

Comment: Do I understand you right that you suggest evaluating the models on joint 2019-2020 data? I do not think this answers the OPs question as the OP is interested in evaluating the models on 2020 data. @RyanVolpi, you may be ignoring the fact that one model has the advantage of being trained on the same data set as being evaluated on while the other model does not. This will bias the test result.

Comment: @RichardHardy I see. I misunderstood the question. I will edit the question.

Comment: @RyanVolpi Yes I misread the question. I think a paired t-test would make more sense.

Comment: @RichardHardy I agree that one model has an advantage but i thought the point is just to prove that the parameters of the 2020 model are better fitted to the 2020 data set than the 2019 model

Comment: Hmm, now that I read the OP, the question is indeed formulated about fitting the data of 2020. I assumed the interest is in the underlying population / data generating process, not the specific sample, as there was the term "test". Otherwise there is nothing to test as one can simply measure the fit of each model on 2020 data and compare the values of the fit criterion.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer which I am not sure about, but I would like to get the idea out in the open.

Use M19 to denote the model estimated on 2019 data and M20 for the one estimated on 2020 data.
Use P19 to denote the predictions of M19 for the 2020.
Use F20 to denote the fitted values of M20 on the 2020 data.
Use L19 to denote the losses from prediction errors corresponding to P19. Specifically, the losses are defined as negative log-likelihood of each observation. If you are fine with evaluating the models by their log-likelihoods, such losses will work fine.

Now use the Diebold-Mariano test with a twist. The ordinary Diebold-Mariano test compares two sets of forecast losses arising from two sets of forecasts of the same set of target values. So it can compare L19 with L20. However, we do not have L20 because we do not have P20, only F20. Here we can employ AIC to help us. We know that AIC estimates twice the negative log-likelihood of observations in the hypothetical case of the model having been fit on another dataset (of the same size and generated by the same data generating process) and used to predict the dataset at hand. Replacing the actual negative log-likelihood of M20 with half the AIC will provide an estimate of L20. From here on, you can compare L19 with the estimated L20 using the Diebold-Mariano test.

I can see two problems with this approach:

1. We do not have the actual L20, only its estimate. My inutition is that this should not be a big problem in large samples, but I could be wrong.
2. The negative log-likelihood may not be your favorite loss. If so, my approach is not directly applicable.

Comment: What is the theoretical problem of using directly only AIC (2k - 2logLoss)?
AIC20 = -2*2 + 2*1020 = 2036 ----
AIC19 = -2*2 + 2*1100 = 2196 ----

the relative likelihood of M19 respect to M20 is then e^((AIC20-AIC19)/2) = 0 ----
Therefore M20 is much better.

Comment: @AM, multiple posts warn against comparing AIC values when the two models are estimated on different samples. However, if you are willing to assume the samples to be generated by the same data generating process (DGP) and we adjust for their different sizes (if the sizes indeed do differ), then I do not see a major problem with that. But I might be overlooking something; I have not seen this done before and as I said, multiple posts warn against that. Menawhile, my approach has the advantage of not assuming that the samples are generated by the same DGP.